# How do you write a dictionary to a csv file in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a dictionary to a csv file and I'm getting an error: "argument 1 must have a "write" method". The dictionary includes a key value associated with a list of authors.

```
  with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['BibCodes', 'Author 1', 'Author 2', 'Author 3']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(ADSclassObj.authorDict)
print (csvfile)
```

Comment: You have a typo `csv -> csvfile`.

Comment: You have a typo: `csv` instead of `csvfile` as the 1st arg to `csv.DictWriter()`.

Answer (score 1):

your file object is named `csvfile` but you're passing the `csv` module to `DictWriter`

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

should be

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

Also if you have a single dict you should use `writerow`  - `writerows` is for when you have a iterable or list of multiple dicts to write:

```
writer.writerows(ADSclassObj.authorDict)
```

should be

```
writer.writerow(ADSclassObj.authorDict)
```

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to help. Now I am getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'"

Comment: @Sam that probably means you should use `writerow` instead of `writerows` since this is a single dict - I edited the answer.